# Hide/Show <div> makes page larger

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm creating a job application form.

When you click to show the div; the page gets bigger both vertically & horizontaly.

Could someone help me to understand why.

Thank you

*Edit: Firefox I noticed the problem.*

Comment: Why not create a JSFiddle. Giving a link will create artificial traffic to the site.

Comment: What browser are you struggling with? Works okay for me in Chrome

Comment: Works fine for me in Chromium too.

Comment: In firefox I noticed the problem.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox on OS X.

Comment: Add screenshots of what is the expected behavior and what actually happens.

Comment: I see, So I'm using firefox on Windows 7. 

When the div is revealed the page scrolls right about 250px and enlarges verticaly about 40px.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox on windows 7 same as IE

Comment: Ive got Firefox (up to date) and it only scrolls up and to the side if the window is very small so that the contant barely fits in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of the form you have a div:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-204px;left:505px;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Application" name="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

which is causing that. set the fixed width for it.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you. Missed that.